# What does for x, *y in list mean in python

Tags: python, list

I recently came across a piece of python code that looked like this

```
groups = {}
    for d, *v in dishes:
        for x in v:
            groups.setdefault(x, []).append(d)
```

dishes represents a 2d array.
What does the 1st for loop statement mean?
What is *v? What does the asterisk before v indicate?
What other situations is an asterisk before a variable used?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's essentially a combination of tuple/list unpacking and `*args` iterable unpacking. Each iterable is getting unpacked on each iteration of the for loop.

First let's look at a simple tuple/list unpacking:

```
>>> x, y = (1, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> y
2

# And now in the context of a loop:
>>> for x, y in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]:
>>>     print(f'x={x}, y={y}')
"x=1, y=2"
"x=3, y=4"
```

Now consider the following (and imagine the same concept within the loop as shown above):

```
>>> x, y = (1, 2, 3)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

>>> x, *y = 1, 2, 3
>>> x
1 
>>> y 
[2, 3]
```

Note how `*` allows `y` to consume all remaining arguments.

This is similar to how you would use `*` in a function - it allows an unspecified number of arguments and it consumes them all.
You can see more examples of `(*args)` usage [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/).

```
>>> def foo(x, *args):
>>>     print(x)
>>>     print(args)

>>>foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
1
[2, 3, 4]
```

As for practical examples, here is a quick one:

```
>>> names = ("Jack", "Johnson", "Senior")
>>> fist_name, *surnames =  names
>>> print(surnames)
["Johnson", "Senior"]
```

Comment: Excellent answer! And I wonder why the last example is considered to be bad?

Comment: I originally had something else. Will edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically * indicates n number of countless elements.

**Example :**

```
x=1,2,4,6,9,8
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
(1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 8)
```

```
y,*x=1,2,4,6,9,8
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
[2, 4, 6, 9, 8]
```